# Magento 2: PWA sample data installation error

Tags: magento2.3.1, sample-data, pwa

I have installed PWA in magento root directory like `magenotpwa231/pwa-studio/`

PWA installed successfully but getting stuck `Repository type is not registered: github` while installing sample data.

I have copy `deployVeniaSampleData.sh` to magento root directory.

**See below path:**

`magenotpwa231/pwa-studio/packages/venia-concept/deployVeniaSampleData.sh` to `magenotpwa231/deployVeniaSampleData.sh and then run the command bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh`

**See the below is the process of run command:**

> cmd: bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh

```
Please specify absolute path to your Magento 2 instance
Magento root folder: /var/www/html/magenotpwa231
Sample data will be installed there.

Are you sure you want to continue? [y/n]y
adding composer repository git@github.com:PMET-public/module-catalog-sample-data-venia.git
adding composer repository git@github.com:PMET-public/module-configurable-sample-data-venia.git
adding composer repository git@github.com:PMET-public/module-customer-sample-data-venia.git
adding composer repository git@github.com:PMET-public/module-sales-sample-data-venia.git
adding composer repository git@github.com:PMET-public/module-tax-sample-data-venia.git
adding composer repository git@github.com:PMET-public/sample-data-media-venia.git
Repository type is not registered: github
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How did you intsalled?can you give me the link?

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-3-pwa-studio-setup/

Comment: need to install graphql and yarn? how to install in windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also faced same issue. After so much trouble and research I found that while we run `bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh` command, Magento tries to find authentication from github.

Please follow below steps to resolve your issue:

1) Copy **auth.json.sample** file placed on Magento root directory and paste it on same place.

2) Rename **auth.json(copy).sample** file to **auth.json** and open it in your editor.

3) Login to [Magento Marketplace](https://marketplace.magento.com/).  If you don’t have an account, click **Register**.

3.1) Click your account name in the top-right of the page and select **My Profile**.

3.2) Click **Access Keys** in the **Marketplace** tab.

3.3) Click Create a New **Access Key**. Enter a specific name for the keys (e.g., the name of the developer receiving the keys) and click **OK**.

3.4) New public and private keys are now associated with your account that you can click to copy. Save this information or keep the page open when working with your Magento project. Use **the Public key as your username** and **the Private key as your password**.

4) Login to [GitHub](https://github.com) account.

4.1) Click your account name in the top-right of the page and select **Settings**.

4.2) Click on **Developer Settings** tab at the last in left sidebar.

4.3) Click on **Personal access token** tab and create your access token. You will get access token which you have to put as value of **github.com** in **auth.json**.

5) `Run php bin/magento cache:flush command`

6) `Run bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh command`

I hope this may helpful to everyone!!

Answer (score 3):

This may happen due to incompatible composer version. Please upgrade your composer to latest version using below code.

```
composer self-update
```

And then try again executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

Edit deployVeniaSampleData.sh search for "--no-interactive-mode" and remove it.  Run bash deployVeniaSampleData.sh again.  Now it will ask you for your github token.